# Conditional formatting. Color cells that are out of range

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have set conditional formatting at both of my column BA and BB. The cells will be filled in color if the values are in the range.

```
Columns("BA:BA").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
    Formula1:="=0.921", Formula2:="=0.931"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5296274
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Columns("BB:BB").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
    Formula1:="=0.069", Formula2:="=0.079"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5296274
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

What code I have to use to make the cells that are not in the range to be filled with other color ?

Comment: Maybe color first whle Spreadsheet (or bigger range) and then change color of selected cells (just idea, I'm not fluent with ExcelVBA)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.FormatConditions.Add - it would seem that you add a new `FormatCondition`, but this time use `xlNotBetween` and a different colour

Comment: @mjsqu hi, can you show me where should I add the xlNotBetween.

Comment: CF always overrides the default fill, so just use @franiis' suggestion and fill the whole range with the other color.